# Service worker delays several minutes before sending controllerchange event

Tags: events, delay, upgrade, service-worker

I am moving our PWA from an appcache install to service workers. Have it working except that upgrades sometimes take over 10 minutes before notifying the client via the controllerchange event.  Sometimes it is almost instant.  I have no idea what the variable is.

```js
let swRegWorker = null;

function showUpdateBar() {
    let snackbar = document.getElementById('snackbar');
    snackbar.className = 'show'
}

// the click event on the pop up notification
document.getElementById('reload').addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.reload()
});

if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/swmobile.js').then(reg => {
        swRegWorker = reg;

        // check for updates every 1 minutes
        setInterval(function(){
            swRegWorker.update()
        }, 1*60000)
    });

    // Listen for claiming of our ServiceWorker
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function(event) {
      console.log('cchange', event);
      showUpdateBar()
    });
}
```

```css
    #snackbar {
        visibility: hidden;
        min-width: 250px;
        margin-left: -125px;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 16px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 30px;
    }

    #snackbar.show {
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s;
        animation: fadein 0.5s;
    }

    #snackbar #reload {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
        from {
            bottom: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            bottom: 30px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @keyframes fadein {
        from {
            bottom: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            bottom: 30px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div>0855</div>

<div id="snackbar">A new version of this app is available.<br/>Click <a id="reload">HERE</a> to update.</div>
```

```js
var CACHE_NAME = 'app-0855';

var urlsToCache = [
    '/',
    '/mobile.html',
    '/manifest.json'
];

self.addEventListener('install',function(e) {
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
        console.log('updating cache to', CACHE_NAME);
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache)
    })
    .then(function() {
        self.skipWaiting()
    })
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    console.log('activate');

    e.waitUntil(
        Promise.all([
            self.clients.claim(),
            caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
                return Promise.all(
                    cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                        if(cacheName !== CACHE_NAME) {
                            console.log('deleting', cacheName);
                            return caches.delete(cacheName);
                        }
                    })
                )
            })
        ])
    )
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
            if(response){
                return response
            }
            // not in cache, return from network
            return fetch(event.request)
        })
    )
});
```

So the app initially installs fine and instantly upon loading.
However, when I modify the html and cache version in the service worker js file, in the next minute I see it download and install the update and see both caches in Chrome devtool temporarily.  Then the old cache is successfully removed.

In perfect cases, the client then pops up the upgrade available message immediately.  But about 50% of the time, for no known reason, it can take 5-30 minutes before the client sees the upgrade popup to refresh and run the new version.

The console logs show that everything is working in the service worker but the self.clients.claim call seems to wait for some amount of indeterminate time before firing the controllerchange event to the client.

I've rewritten a million times and read every tutorial I can find, starting with Google's service worker lifetime cycle documentation.  I'm at a loss.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved it.  I had a small test page that always worked as the spec design says, but in our "real" app, this mysterious delay kept appearing.

As it turns out, it is our use of SSEs (server sent events, or EventSource) that seemed to "lock up" an active instance of the service worker.

I added the following code in the fetch handler and all delays seemed to have gone away!

```js
    const request = event.request;
    const acceptHeader = request.headers.get('Accept');
    const url = request.url;

    if(acceptHeader.includes('text/event-stream') || url.indexOf('events') !== -1 || url.indexOf('api') !== -1) {
        console.log('ignoring', url);
        return
    }
```

While I believe the above solved 99% of the issue, I still had one instance on my phone where the controllerchange notification never happened.  So as a safeguard, I also added this in the service worker file and in the client which seems redundant, but is benign and gives a 100% success rate of upgrade notifications.

```js
function send_message_to_client(client, msg) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var msg_chan = new MessageChannel();

        msg_chan.port1.onmessage = function(event){
            if(event.data.error){
                reject(event.data.error);
            }
            else{
                resolve(event.data);
            }
        };

        client.postMessage("SW says: '"+msg+"'", [msg_chan.port2]);
    });
}


function send_message_to_all_clients(msg) {
    clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
        clients.forEach(client => {
            send_message_to_client(client, msg).then(m => console.log("SW Received Message: "+m));
        })
    })
}


self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    console.log('activate');
    send_message_to_all_clients('Upgrade ready!') // the NEW line

    e.waitUntil(
        Promise.all([
            self.clients.claim(),
            caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
                return Promise.all(
                    cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                        if(cacheName !== CACHE_NAME) {
                            console.log('deleting', cacheName);
                            return caches.delete(cacheName);
                        }
                    })
                )
            })
        ])
        .then(function() {
            console.log('promises kept')
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('promises broken', err)
        })
    )
});
```

```html
    // handler for messages coming from the service worker
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        console.log("client received: " + event.data);
        showUpdateBar()
    });
```